# JQuery - can't delete table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I don't know what is an error in this code. I have correctly detect parent. But doesn't work.

This is HTML code

```
<table>

    <tbody class="tbody">
        <tr id="row_1">
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="row_1_jumlah_1" name="row_1_jumlah_1" value="1" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <input type="button" class="btn green" value="Tambah Satuan" id="add_row" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left:10px;" />
    </tbody>

</table>
```

This is js code

```
$("#add_row").click(function () {
    var last_index_tr = $(".tbody tr").length;
    var new_index_tr = $(".tbody tr").length + 1;
    var row = $("<tr id='row_" + new_index_tr + "'>");
    var input = $("<td>     <input  class='form-control' type='text' id='row_" + new_index_tr + "_jumlah_1' name='row_" + new_index_tr + "_jumlah_1' value='1'  readonly='readonly' /> </td>");
    var action_delete = $("<td> <input class='btn btn-danger' type='button' id='row_" + new_index_tr + "_delete' class='delete' value='delete' /> </td>");

    action_delete.click(function () {
        var parent_1 = action_delete.parent();

        var get_tr_parent_id = $(parent_1).attr('id');
        //document.write(get_tr_parent_id); 
        $("#".get_tr_parent_id).remove();
    });


    row.append(input);
    row.append(action_delete);
    row.append("</tr>");
    $(".tbody").append(row);
});
```

I want to remove tr inside table with delete button or action_delete(see js code). I have get parent perfectly. But I can't still delete tr.

Comment: I have try to make reader understand :(. I'm newbie

Comment: I just know my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,  You can use `.on` to hook the `click handler` for that `delete button` which is being created at runtime. Though your hooking is working, Using `.on` is a good practice while dealing with `elements` which are created `dynamically`. And by the way you have to concatenate the `#` with `+` Not with `.` That was the problem with your code, See your code working over [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LeF5V/1/).

```
var action_delete = $("<td> <input class='btn btn-danger' type='button' id='row_" + new_index_tr   +"_delete' class='delete' value='delete' /> </td>"); 

$(document).on('click',"#row_" + new_index_tr +"_delete",function(){
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LeF5V/)

---

### Edit:

Try the following code, This will register to the click event commonly only once for your entire delete buttons.

```
$("#add_row").click(function () {
    var last_index_tr = $(".tbody tr").length;
    var new_index_tr = $(".tbody tr").length + 1;
    var row = $("<tr id='row_" + new_index_tr + "'>");
    var input = $("<td>     <input  class='form-control' type='text' id='row_" + new_index_tr + "_jumlah_1' name='row_" + new_index_tr + "_jumlah_1' value='1'  readonly='readonly' /> </td>");
    var action_delete = $("<td> <input class='btn btn-danger' type='button' id='row_" + new_index_tr + "_delete' class='delete' value='delete' /> </td>");  

    row.append(input);
    row.append(action_delete);
    row.append("</tr>");
    $(".tbody").append(row);
});

$(document).on('click', "input[type='button'][id$='delete']",function(){
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

### [DEMO - I](http://jsfiddle.net/LeF5V/3/)

Comment: I wasn't the one downvoting, but this no better than directly attaching the event handler on the `<td>`, since you create separate handlers for every `<td>` (It's actually a little worse, because of the way browsers handle event bubbling). The best way would be to only subscribe to the click event once. (By a selector matching all the buttons).

Comment: @SoonDead I had updated the code. Thanks for pointing out what's wrong.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeF5V/5/) as there were funny things left in it. Feel free to use some of the changes in your answer.

Comment: @SoonDead Man You just made lot of efforts towards this problem. Really great. I appreciate it.!

Comment: @AndikaK No bad things, We just cleaned up your code. So as a result it would also improve the efficiency.

Comment: @AndikaK There were some bad things, like the `row.append("</tr>")` which makes no sense. Look at [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), it is not string building, but building DOM elements. The completely unnecessary variable `var last_index_tr = $(".tbody tr").length;` is never used. Look at my fiddle, I have written some comments in the javascript about the changes.

Comment: Also you have written: `var parent_1 = action_delete.parent(); var get_tr_parent_id = $(parent_1).attr('id'); $("#".get_tr_parent_id).remove();` but this is unnecessary. You select an element with `action_delete.parent()`. You get the `id` of this element. Then you select an element with that id! This is the same element you have selected before, you have just wasted processor time and memory to select the same element again! You could just have written: `action_delete.parent().remove()`!

Comment: @SoonDead + Rajaprabhu Aravubdasamy thanks for give solution very good

Answer (score 0):

Your remove method is incorrect. It should be:

```
$("#" + get_tr_parent_id).remove();
```

It was currently returning undefined instead of concatenating the two strings.

Comment: I tested it on your code; this fixed the error. The selected answer rewrote the problem entirely.